# cannot build android app manifest merger failed

Tags: android, google-play-services, react-native

I have been trying to fix this for whole day, and still I am getting error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>     is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).  Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

I dont know how come com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1 is set to 26.0.1 while I cannot find this inside app.gradle dependecies.

I am sure that should be 26.1.0 but I just cant find the place where to modify it!

ANyone have any idea about this?

Also for strange reason this sometimes fixes but its not reliable.

```
    configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
      if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
        details.useVersion '26.1.0'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if I restart android studio or try to rebuild it does not work , then after trying for some time it works, it just so headache!

Comment: Add your own dependency for `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0`, to get Gradle to use the newer version. Most likely some library that you are depending on is where the `recyclerview-v7` dependency is coming from, and you cannot modify that directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare, now i get different error: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuz;

Comment: also I had to actually add : compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0';
  compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0';
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0';

Comment: also the issue is causing when I add compile project(':react-native-onesignal') , without this the app build succesfully!